# How to make smooth transitions between the splash screen and the main screen?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

all! I'm working on a `React Native` project, but I'm new to this tech stack. Currently, I want to make the transitions between the splash screen and the main screen much smoother, and I have searched for solutions from `ChatGpt`, but they are not working. How can I fix this issue?

Here is my code:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { Animated, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Link, NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';


import HomeScreen from "./src/screens/HomeScreen";
import ProfileScreen from "./src/screens/ProfileScreen";
import AlertScreen from "./src/screens/AlertScreen";

import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { useEffect, useState, useCallback, useRef } from 'react';

import * as SplashScreen from "expo-splash-screen";
// Keep the splash screen visible while we fetch resources
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();


export default function App() {
  const [appIsReady, setAppIsReady] = useState(false);
  const opacity = useRef(new Animated.Value(1)).current;

  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
  const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

  const screenOptions = ({ route }) => ({
    tabBarIcon: ({ foucused, color, size }) => {
      let iconName;
      if (route.name === "Home") {
        iconName = foucused ? "ios-home" : "ios-home-outline";
      } else if (route.name === "Alert") {
        iconName = foucused ? "ios-alert-circle" : "ios-alert-circle-outline";
      } else {
        iconName = foucused ? "person-circle" : "person-circle-outline";
      }

      return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
    },
    tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'gray',
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    const prepareApp = async () => {
      // 执行其他异步的准备操作
      try {
        // await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
      } catch (e) {
        console.warn(e);
      } finally {
        // Tell the application to render
        setAppIsReady(true);
      }
    };
    prepareApp();
  }, []);

  const hideSplashScreen = async () => {
    await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
  };

  const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
    if (appIsReady) {
      Animated.timing(opacity, {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 1000,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }).start(hideSplashScreen);
    }
  }, [appIsReady]);

  if (!appIsReady) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <Animated.View onLayout={onLayoutRootView} style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      < NavigationContainer>
        < Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" screenOptions={screenOptions} >
          <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{ title: "首页" }} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Alert" component={AlertScreen} options={{ title: "告警", tabBarBadge: 3 }} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} options={{ title: "我" }} />
          {/* 添加其他导航屏幕 */}
        </Tab.Navigator >
        <StatusBar animated={true} style='light' />
      </NavigationContainer >
    </Animated.View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },

});
```

And this is the `package.json` for my project:

```
{
  "name": "comnova-net",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "expo": "~48.0.15",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.7",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.20.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

If there is any problems with my description, please let me know.

Comment: Did you have any luck figuring it out?

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but there is a **[pretty easy to follow example on github](https://github.com/expo/examples/tree/master/with-splash-screen)**.

Here is how they do it:

- use `SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync()` to prevent auto hiding the default splash screen
- create a component that exactly mimics the default splash screen, for that you can use variables like `Constants.expoConfig.splash.image`, `.splash.resizeMode` and `.splash.backgroundColor`
- preload the custom splash screen image so it is ready to display without extra loading time
- When preloaded, use `await SplashScreen.hideAsync()` to hie the default splash screen
- it should be pretty easy for the transition with your custom splash screen to be invisible (in my case I needed an extra delay before hiding for the custom splash to appear directly)
- At this point you can do anything using [react native animation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/animations) for example, like fade, scale...

I hope it's clear enough, feel free to ask for more details if needed